# RelativeLayout and ScrollView

Tags: java, android

I have a problem about RelativeLayout,i dunno know how to add a scrollview,i want to keep all my object in a relative layout and i dont want to add another linearlayout,also please notice that i have a background set in my RelativeLayout,Thanks you,i also have a problem when using .gone function for my imageview in a relative layout,the image reapear when the view is updated,i had not this pb when using a linearlayout here is my code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:background="@drawable/questionggreen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >






    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" 24 Juin 1944"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" 9 Decembre 1988"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="14 octobre 1978"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Chrono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/QuestionNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.26"
        android:text="Question 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/QuestionNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Quelle est la date de naissance de Usher ?"
        android:textColor="#FFFACD"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Question"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mzl"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.26"
        android:text="CELB"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:text="Correct :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#00ff00" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:text="Wrong :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Goodanswercount"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Wronganswercount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/QuestionNumber"
        android:text="La reponse etait :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lareponsecorrectetait"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scores1"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Scores1"
        android:text="Scores : 00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonok" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:text="Sounds Off" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Quit" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  it's helpful for you...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1"
 android:background="@drawable/background">
<ScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_weight="0.97">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"   android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="444dp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textColor="@color/myGreenColor" android:text="Enter Roll Number and Exam hear" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:src="@drawable/result" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="22dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageView>
        <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginTop="32dp" android:layout_width="150dp" android:id="@+id/searchRsult_spinner"></Spinner>
        <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:inputType="text|textPersonName" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/searchRsult_spinner" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/searchResult_txtRollNumber">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Show result"    android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_below="@+id/searchResult_txtRollNumber" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="33dp" android:layout_width="200dp" android:textColor="@color/myColorBlue"></Button>
        <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Cancel" android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:textColor="@color/myColorBlue"></Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
 <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.80"
    android:background="@drawable/questionggreen"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >






    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:clipToPadding="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" 24 Juin 1944"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=" 9 Decembre 1988"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="14 octobre 1978"
            android:textColor="#ff00ff"
            android:textSize="19dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />




        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Chrono"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_marginTop="2dp"/>

    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/QuestionNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.26"
        android:text="Question 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/QuestionNumber"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Quelle est la date de naissance de Usher ?"
        android:textColor="#FFFACD"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="158dp"
        android:layout_height="154dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/Question"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mzl"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.26"
        android:text="CELB"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#00ff00"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:text="Correct :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#00ff00" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Goodanswercount"
        android:text="Wrong :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Goodanswercount"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Wronganswercount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ff0000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/QuestionNumber"
        android:text="La reponse etait :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Lareponsecorrectetait"
        android:layout_width="215dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Lareponseetait"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scores1"
        android:layout_width="29dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="000"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scores"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/Question"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Scores1"
        android:text="Scores : 00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#ff00ff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buttonok" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:text="Sounds Off" android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Quit" />

 </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much its work,but now,i wanna Disable the scrollview when i dont need it,also,i wanna hide the image view with picture.setvisibility(View.GONE) in the onCreate method,its work at start up,but when the GUI is updated,the imageview come back again

Comment: Try to do this in the onResume() method

Comment: doesnot work using onResume() method,also it is possible to disable the scrolling when i dont need it ? thanks.

Comment: I don't think is possible, you need to know when the view is update to reset the visiblity on gone.